# How to join a table multiple times using same column but related different tables? (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, join, count

My scenario is for a cargo company. I have Shipments, Senders, Recievers and Cities tables.
Shipments table holds shipment_category, sender_id, reciever_id. Cities table holds ID and city_name. Sender table holds sender_id, sender_city which equal to ID of cities table. Recievers table holds reciever_id and reciever_city which equal to ID of cities table.

I managed to show shipments which are belongs to category1 and have different coordinations and count of them by ID of cities like

From_City  || To_City ||  COUNT

1205 || 1346 || 7

I use the code below:

```
SELECT  S.city AS From_City, R.city AS To_City , COUNT( * ) 
FROM Shipments Sh, Recievers R, Senders S
WHERE SH.category=1
AND SH.sender_id = S.ID
AND SH.reciever_id = R.ID
GROUP BY From_City, To_City
ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC
```

What I want is to get same table by city names from cities table like below:

From_City || To_City || Count

Paris || London || 7

Note:
Please don't recommend to change database tables. That is just a sample to express my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT
    `sender_cities`.`city_name` AS `From_City`,
    `receiver_cities`.`city_name` AS `To_City`,
    COUNT(*) as `Count`
FROM 
    `shipments` `ship`
    INNER JOIN `senders` `s` ON (`ship`.`sender_id` = `s`.`sender_city`)
    INNER JOIN `cities` `sender_cities` ON (`s`.`sender_city` = `sender_cities`.`city_id`)
    INNER JOIN `receivers` `r` ON (`ship`.`receiver_id` = `r`.`sender_city`)
    INNER JOIN `cities` `receiver_cities` ON (`r`.`receiver_city` = `receiver_cities`.`city_id`)
GROUP BY 
    `From_City`,
    `To_City`
ORDER BY 
    `Count` DESC
```

Comment: you beat me to it! this would have been near exact to my answer.

Comment: would your answer differ in the logic in any way?

Comment: No, only with capitalizing reserved MySQL words and indenting code, only because I hate messy code. It makes it hard for even me to read and quickly understand later on. Just, one thing I learned from the school of Hard Knocks.

Comment: I agree to that. It's better to write clean, readable and indented code.